# Laravel : Webhook class not found - Captain Hook

Tags: notifications, laravel-5, webhooks

I'm trying to use [captain-hook](https://github.com/mpociot/captainhook#webhook) package to make webhook in my laravel app so that I can send a notification to a specific user when an eloquent event is fired.

I followed the [package's documentation](https://github.com/mpociot/captainhook#webhook) and put this code at the end of the method that will fire the event :

```
Webhook::create([
        "url" => Input::get("url"),
        "event" => "eloquent.saved: \App\DoctorRequest",
        "tenant_id" => $user->id
    ]);
```

but I get this error : 
FatalThrowableError in DoctorRequestController.php line 109:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Webhook' not found

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't imported this in your controller.

Assuming you've added the Service Provider in your `config/app.php` file then you just need to import it at the top of your controller with:

`use Webhook;`

If you don't wish to import the Facade then you can reference it like this instead:

```
\Webhook::create([
    "url" => Input::get("url"),
    "event" => "eloquent.saved: \App\DoctorRequest",
    "tenant_id" => $user->id
]);
```

Comment: What Facade should I add ? I only added the Provider as referred to in the documentation : Mpociot\CaptainHook\CaptainHookServiceProvider::class   @James

Comment: @RowaydaKhayri sorry, I see this package is just using a Service Provider. You still need to reference the Facade in your controller though. Have updated my answer.

Comment: still getting this error after importing it : Class 'Webhook' not found !